# Neo4j lsof: command not found at db server startup

Tags: neo4j

I am getting an endless stream of errors (as follows) when attempting to start the database server - until I am stopping it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal.  Does anyone have idea what is wrong?

> $ rake neo4j:start
>
> Starting Neo4j development... 
> db/neo4j/development/bin/neo4j: line 147: lsof: command not found
> db/neo4j/development/bin/neo4j: line 147: lsof: command not found
> db/neo4j/development/bin/neo4j: line 147: lsof: command not found
> db/neo4j/development/bin/neo4j: line 147: lsof: command not found
>
> ^C
> rake aborted!
>
> Interrupt:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this after I added /usr/sbin to the PATH.
Here it is:
levi$ echo $PATH
/Users/levi/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/:/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin

Answer (score 1):

For me the below worked:

```
yum install lsof
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead lsof ,,,,,, Try to use

/usr/sbin/lsof $FILE

Where $FILE is path of a file

Answer (score 0):

According to [colucix](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/lsof-command-not-found-centos-906882/), the lsof command is available only to root.
if you want to run it as a non root user, you can specify its full path.

```
$ /usr/sbin/lsof /path/to/some/file
```

Also [Philip Reynolds](https://serverfault.com/a/87296) has pointed out that you can specify an sudo alias for lsof if it suites you.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 16.04 it worked after installing `lsof`

```
sudo apt-get install lsof
```